# Can the converse of this predicate axiom be proved a theorem?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, axioms

In predicate calculus, one of the logical axioms is given like:

> Let $p,q$ be any formulae in predicate calculus and variable $x$ is not free in $p$ (or doesn't occur), then the formula below is an axiom:
> $$
> \forall x(p\to q)\to (p\to \forall x q).
> $$

I'm wondering if the formula below is a theorem, given $x$ does not occur in $p$:
$$
(p\to \forall x q)\to \forall x(p\to q).
$$

**MY PROGRESS**

I tried these steps of inference:

1. $p\to \forall x q$
2. $\forall x q\to q$$\qquad$(Predicate axiom)
3. $(s\to t)\wedge (t\to u)\to (s\to u)$$\qquad$(Tautology)
4. $p\to q$$\qquad$(By 1. and 2.)
5. $\forall x(p\to q)$$\qquad$(Generalization)

But I can't show these steps are correct, especially step 2. and 4.

Comment: Have you tried proving it? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ShyPerson I tried these steps: $p\to \forall xq$ implies $p\to q$, and by generalization, $\forall x(p\to q)$, but I can't show the first step of inference is correct.

Comment: What proof system are you using?

Comment: @ShyPerson The common predicate calculus system, with tautologies, predicate axioms and axioms of equality as logical axioms and modus ponens, generalization as laws of inferences.

Comment: Yes, your first step in your comments is correct. So if I rewrite it as follows, what is the next thing to try? $\{(p\to \forall x q)\} \vdash p\to q$

Comment: @ShyPerson Will it be $\forall xq\to q$? If so then everything's done. This is similar to one of the quantifier axioms, but that looks like $\forall x q(x)\to q(t)$.

Comment: @ShyPerson I've understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The converse of the axiom is a theorem and the proof is correct.

I am accustomed to the system given in John Kelly's *The Essence of Logic*:

[image]

Instead of the 3rd line, Kelly employs a derived rule called *transitivity of implication* (TI) (proved in the chapter on propositional calculus):

[image]